# Testing the eval function of GNU make

Tags: makefile

The GNU make manual says that the eval function expands the arguments and then feeds the results of the expansion to make parser. The following is quoted from GNU make manual.

```
The argument to the eval function is expanded, then the results of that expansion are parsed as makefile syntax.
```

I don't quite understand how the make parser process the text fed by eval, so
I write following makefile to test.

```
define myprint
    echo "this is a line"
endef

goal:
    $(eval $(call myprint))
    gcc -o goal test.c
```

I know that the correct invocation of `myprint` should be only use the call function: `$(call myprint)` and delete the 'Tab' character before echo. I write the makefile in this form just to test the eval function.

My expectation: first the eval function expands myprint, which is an echo command preceded by a 'Tab', and the 'Tab' is  used to make the expanded text to be a legal recipe. Then the eval feeds the expanded text to maker parser, who will identify the text to be a recipe, and run it. As the command is legal, the makefile should run properly.

However, I meet such an error:

```
Makefile:6: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

Could somebody explain why make produce such an error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> the results of that expansion are parsed as makefile syntax

Your use of `eval` is different: you would like it to be parsed as shell syntax. You can write:

```
define myprint
echo "this is a line"
endef

goal:
    $(myprint)
    gcc -o goal test.c
```

or:

```
define myprint
echo "this is a $(1)"
endef

goal:
    $(call myprint,line)
    gcc -o goal test.c
```

Because after make expansion the recipes are valid shell syntax. But not what you wrote because the expansion of `eval` is still interpreted as make syntax, not shell. To illustrate a typical use of `eval` and `call`, consider this:

```
define myprint
echo "this is a $(1)"
endef

define mygoal
$(1):
    $$(call myprint,line)
    gcc -o $(1) $(2).c
endef
$(eval $(call mygoal,goal,test))
```

It is a bit more tricky than two first examples (without `eval`) but it illustrates the real purpose of `eval`: programmatically instantiate make constructs. Here is how it works, step by step:

During the **first** phase of its 2-phases algorithm, make expands the `$(eval...` function call, that is:

1. Expand the parameter of the `$(eval...` function (the `$(call...` function):

   1. Expand the parameters of the `$(call...` function (`goal` and `test`). No effect in our case.
   2. Assign the result to the temporary variables `$(1)` and `$(2)`.
   3. Expand the `mygoal` variable in this context, which replaces `$(1)`, `$(2)` and `$$(call...` by `goal`, `test` and `$(call...`, respectively.
2. Instantiates (in memory) the result as a make construct, a complete rule in this case:

   ```
   goal:
       $(call myprint,line)
       gcc -o goal test.c
   ```

The first phase continues but it has no effect on this instantiated rule because the recipes are expanded by make during the **second** phase.

During the second phase, when the time comes to build the `goal` target, make expands the recipe before executing it, that is:

1. Expand the `$(call myprint...` parameter (`line`, no effect).
2. Assign the result to temporary parameter `$(1)`.
3. Expand variable `myprint` in this context, which produces:

   ```
   echo "this is a line"
   ```

All this is thus the same as if we had written the rule:

```
goal:
    echo "this is a line"
    gcc -o goal test.c
```

Note the double `$$` in the initial definition of `mygoal`:

> It’s important to realize that the eval argument is expanded twice;
>   first by the eval function, then the results of that expansion are
>   expanded again when they are parsed as makefile syntax. This means you
>   may need to provide extra levels of escaping for “$” characters when
>   using eval.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply and examples. I think I get the point which confuse me: after the first expansion of the argument, the results will be send to make parser as regular make syntax. I think the echo command preceded by a 'Tab' is not a regular syntax. That's why my makefile doesn't run properly. Is my understanding right?

Comment: No, not exactly. The problem is not tabs. Try it yourself, remove this leading tab. You will still get an error because, at the end, `$(eval $(call myprint))` expands as make statements while it should be plain shell. It is the same problem as if you were putting `CFLAGS := -g` in a recipe: make syntax where shell is expected.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to explain this better than what Florian already wrote. Try maybe to read again this part of the documentation and meditate it: *The argument to the eval function is expanded, then the results of that expansion are parsed as makefile syntax. The expanded results can define new make variables, targets, implicit or explicit rules, etc.* Insist, maybe, on **as makefile syntax**.

Comment: Sorry for my act of deletion. I'm not familiar how to write code in comments. Following is my before comments.
Do you mean that the problem is that the source to eval should be make syntax?  I tried following makefile after your suggestion, and it works.
[define mydef
a = test.c
endef

goal:
 $(eval $(call mydef))
 echo $(a)
 gcc –o goal test.c]

Comment: There is something important to understand with `eval`: it returns the empty string. What you tried works because if you replace the `$(eval...` by the empty string (but leave the leading tab), and add `a = test.c` elsewhere, your makefile is still valid. You define a make variable in the context of a recipe, which is a bit weird, but apparently GNU make tolerates this. If you try, instead, to define another complete make construct like a rule (target+prerequisites+recipe), it does not work because you cannot have this in the context of a recipe.

Comment: Yes, my usage of eval function is unusual. The example is only used to clear my confusion about GNU make, not for practical projects. In the example, the eval function makes a = test.c parsed by make parser, and although the eval function returns null, but it indeed affects make. I  do an experiment, and it shows that the echo $(a) command outputs 'test.c', so a = test.c really takes effect.

Comment: Yes, it affects make, because it is instantiated by `eval` and then expanded during the second phase of the make algorithm. But it is not instantiated *in-place* in the recipe. It is instantiated in the in-memory data structure that make builds and uses. In the recipe it is replaced by the empty string, reason why: 1) the recipe works and 2) the make variable is indeed assigned, at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation:)

Answer (score 5):

`$(eval …)` needs a syntactically complete makefile fragment.  It cannot be used to paste tokens into other makefile constructs.  Perhaps the manual does not explain this clearly enough, but it's implemented by reading its argument as if it were an included makefile.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very clear. The echo command preceded by a 'Tab' is not syntactically complete.

Answer (score 0):

@RenaudPacalet, I write following makefile to test whether the expansion of call 'eats' one dollar.

```
define myprint
echo "In my print $$(ls)"
endef

goal:
    $(call myprint)
    $(info $(call myprint))
    gcc -o goal test.c
```

Its output is:

```
echo "In my print $(ls)"
echo "In my print $(ls)"
In my print call.mk ... (files list)
```

As `$(call myprint)` outputs `"In my print $(ls)"` correctly, it must be expanded to `echo "In my print $$(ls)"` first, then it will be expanded to the correct shell command `echo "In my print $(ls)"`. So I think the call function does not 'eats' one dollar.

Another evidence is the output of info function. The GNU make manual says:

```
$(info text…)
This function does nothing more than print its (expanded) argument(s) to standard output.
```

From the manual we can infer that make will expand the arguments of the info function. As the output of the info is `echo "In my print $(ls)"`, so the arguments before expansion should be `echo "In my print $$(ls)"`. So we can conclude that the call function doesn't 'eat' one dollar.

Comment: What you apparently do not understand is that the expansion is recursive. When make runs the `goal` recipe it expands it line by line. When  expanding `$(info $(call myprint))`, it first expands the parameter of `$(info`, that is `$(call myprint)`. When expanding `$(call myprint)` it first expands `myprint` (no effect) and then, it expands the value of `myprint` and eats one `$`. The result `echo "In my print $(ls)"` is the final expanded parameter of `$(info...` and thus what `$(info...` prints when make evaluates it. Note: you don't have to put `info` in a recipe.

Comment: Just put `$(info $(call myprint))` flat in your Makefile and what you will see is the result of the expansion of `$(call myprint)`, with one `$` eaten. What `info` outputs on the standard output is exactly what is passed to `$(eval...` when using `$(eval $(call myprint))`. The only difference is that `$(info...` just sends it to the standard output while `$(eval...` evaluates it and thus instantiates it as a make construct. This was an interesting discussion.

Comment: If the expanded parameter of `$(eval ...` is `"In my print $(ls)"` (with one dollar), I don't think the make would run properly, as make would expands `$(ls)` to null, and this command wouldn't run properly.  I think the parameters after expansion to `$(eval... or $(info...` should have two dollars.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Finally I get where my misunderstanding of the expansion: I misunderstood that there was a return value from `$call` which would be expanded again by `$eval`. Actually there is no such unnecessary step. Thanks again for your detailed explanation.